# Why "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because ... cant be used as index" error still shown even if I already typeguard-ed it?

Tags: typescript

[image: Error prompt]

I want to do the best practice possible, so first I check if the `propertyKey` is property of `objectParent`. Here's my playground code

```
const objectParent = {
  product: 'this is product',
  shipping: 'this is shipping',
};

const firstOne = false;

const displayOrder = firstOne
  ? (['a', 'b'] as const)
  : (['a', 'b', 'c', 'product', 'shipping'] as const);

for (const propertyKey of displayOrder) {
  if (propertyKey in objectParent) {
    console.log(objectParent[propertyKey]);
  }
}
```

I expect that since I already added a typeguard using `if (propertyKey in objectParent)`, typescript should allow me using `propertyKey` as the index. I know you can bypass this using `propertyKey as keyof typeof objectParent` but I feel like that's not a solution since kinda lazy writing

Comment: The Error is coming because Property 'a' does not exist on objectParent variable.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but I already added the typeguard, Isn't it supposed to make the type not "implicitly any"? Since it will always return the correct/existing `propertyKey`

Comment: try `objectParent[propertyKey as keyof typeof objectParent]`

Comment: I already considered that in the description above in case you missed it. Btw just run into this, as it turns out its been a discussion since considering the `in` operator as a type guard hasn't yet applied in current typescript

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here arises from the fact Type Script is a compiled language, and your check is dynamic. In normal JS,

`if(propertyKey in objectParent)`

would suffice, since everything is dynamic, and during runtime the indexing is guaranteed to be what you want. Of course, in that case you could index with anything and just get `undefined`, which is part of the thing TS is trying to work against.

Thus, a compile time hint for `propertyKey` needs to be provided, to let the compiler know that the index type is valid for indexing. This as simple as

`propertyKey as keyof typeof objectParent`

which is essentially telling the compiler to trust you, and you will ensure in runtime the values are valid index values - of course, now it's up to you to not make mistakes (such as forgetting the `if` guard).

This goes somewhat against the spirit of being type safe though, and it seems this is a perfect case for the object itself carrying the display order with it. If multiple different objects need to be supported, it suffices they provide a display order interface which a function can use to display them all.

Comment: Firstly thanks for answering. But I think my question is kinda make sense since there are other use cases that similar to this one, e.g. lets say `objectParent` possibly has another child that is a `Function`, then we can do `if (!!objectParent.anotherChild) return objectParent.anotherChild()`. That example will led to typescript not showing any error warning since we already typeguard-ed it using the `if(...)`. Its kinda similar to this case don't you think? the only difference is this one is using an `in` operator.

Comment: Your question is perfectly legitimate and points to an important difference between TS and JS. In your question you are using something to index with a type which is not the type expected by the object, unlike your example in the comment where you are explicitly using an object by itself with methods that exist on it, so there is no type problem. That is indeed a good solution to type safety.

Comment: icic, I get it now thanks!